# Testing python Azure function app before deployment using Github Workflows

Tags: python, azure, github, azure-functions, github-actions

I have a python function app that I want I am deploying to Azure using a github standard workflow. I want to add a job before deploying that also runs all the units tests for the function. Locally, I am using pytest to run the unit tests. The structure of the folders is as shown below.

[image]

When running locally I do 'python -m pytest tests' and it runs all the tests.

When I add the same thing in the github workflow it gives me error
**ERROR: file or directory not found: tests**

The job is described as:

[image]

Is there a way to run the tests using the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by using the command

`python -m pytest ./function/tests`